# How to change the text of radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with radiobutton and two choices `("yourself"/"a colleague")`.

In that form, I have added a `button` for translation.

When I click on the button, I want to change tect of the radiobutton to french `("Vous-même" / "Un collegue")`.

I just need the jQuery line that allow me to make this change.

I try this :

NWF`$('#'+UserTypeID).find("input:checked").val("Vous-même");`
Change the value but not the text.

NWF`$('#'+UserTypeID).find("input:checked").text("Vous-même");`
Generate error because this line completely hide the radiobutton

Someone have solution ?

Comment: You need the label that goes with the input, not the input itself.

Comment: A radio input hasn't any text because it is a void element, it hasn't any closing tag. You probably mean following text node **or** relevant radio label. But without seeing any relevant HTML markup, then...

Answer (score 0):

If you have html like this:

```
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<input type="radio" id="foo" name="type"/>
<label for="bar">Bar</label>
<input type="radio" id="bar" name="type"/>
```

then you can change the text using:

```
NWF$('#'+UserTypeID).find('[for="foo"]').text("Vous-même");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for example using :

`label` to be able to change the text corresponding to the radio buttons.

`data` attributes to save your data that you have to switch on each button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.translate').click(function(){
   $('input[type=radio][name=person]').each(function( index ) {
       var current_element=$(this);
       var done=false;
       var traductions=[current_element.data('traduction-fr'),current_element.data('traduction-en')];
       var current_value=$("label[for='" +current_element.attr("id")+ "']").text();
        $.each(traductions, function( index, value ) {
             if(current_value!= value && !done){
                $("label[for='" + current_element.attr("id")+ "']").text(value); done=true;
            }
         });
     });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="option1">yourself</label>
  <input type="radio" name="person" id="option1" value="person_1" data-traduction-fr="Vous-même" data-traduction-en="yourself"><br>
  <label for="option2">a colleague</label>
  <input type="radio" name="person" id="option2" value="person_2" data-traduction-fr="Un collegue" data-traduction-en="a colleague"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" class="translate">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery map function

```
  <label for="option1" data-selected="en" data-en="yourself" data-fr="Vous-même">yourself</label>
<input type="radio" name="person" id="option1"/>

<label for="option2" data-selected="en" data-en="a colleague" data-fr="Un collegue">a colleague</label>
<input type="radio" name="person" id="option2"/>
```

Use the below code

```
var $labels = $("label[for]");
 $('input').map(function(){
        var label = $labels.filter('[for="'+this.id+'"]');
        var lang =label.attr("data-selected"),
            enText = label.attr("data-en"),
            frText = label.attr("data-fr");
    if("en" == lang){
        label.text(frText);
        label.attr("data-selected", "fr")
    }else{
        label.text(euText);
        label.attr("data-selected", "en")    
    }   
});
```